# Access is denied while start or stop window service remotely

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-services

I designed a window service(S1) in c++  which can start or stop a service remotely .
this service is working fine when i run this as a process.
But it's not working when i add this into service manager and run under the local system account  in this case OpenSCManager return 0(access denied).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //this is sample code not complete service code//
  char *premote_server= "192.168.122.100";

    ImpersonateUser();

    //access service control manager
    SC_HANDLE hSCM = ::OpenSCManager(premote_server,
                       SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE,
                       SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

 DWORD dwError = GetLastError(); //dwError is 5 which is Acess is denied.

    if (hSCM == 0)
    {
      printf("ERROR: UNABLE TO OPEN SERVICE MANAGER\n");
      PrintError(GetLastError());
      return;
    }
  StopSvc(hSCM, 'servicename');
::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);

  delete[] pName;

return 0;
}

void ImpersonateUser()
{
  //prepare to access remote system

  DWORD id = GetCurrentProcessId();
  HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, id);

  HANDLE t;

  BOOL b = OpenProcessToken( hp,
                             TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE ,
                             &t);

  if(!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(t))
  {
    PrintError(GetLastError());
    return;
  }
 CloseHandle(hp); //close handle
 CloseHandle(t);
}
void StopSvc(SC_HANDLE hSCM,, char *szSvcName)
{
    SC_HANDLE hService = ::OpenService(hSCM, 
                                       szSvcName,
                                       SERVICE_STOP);

    if (hService == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: COULDN'T OPEN SERVICE\n");
        return;
    }

    SERVICE_STATUS status;
    if(!::ControlService(hService, 
                         SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,
                         &status))
    printf("ERROR: COULDN'T STOP SERVICE\n");


    ::CloseServiceHandle(hService);

    QuerySvc(szNetworkName, szSvcName);
}
```

**Note :**
 1. I have admin rights on my local system as well as remote system.
 2. I can not change service Log On properties because of other functionality.
3.I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for development.

Comment: You don't need your ImpersonateUser() function since it does the same thing as the built-in ImpersonateSelf() API.  Actually you don't need that either; you're not doing anything for which self-impersonation is useful.

Comment: Hi @Harry Johnston  thanks. it's working  but is it safe to add LOCALCOMPUTERNAME into the remote computer's Administrators group ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have admin rights on remote system

but how remote system know this ? you need somehow first connect to `\IPC$` resource on remote machine with user name/password. this can be done for example with [`NetUseAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370645(v=vs.85).aspx) .try code like this:

```
#include <Lm.h>

ULONG RemoteTest(PCWSTR lpMachineName, PCWSTR username, PCWSTR password, PCWSTR lpServiceName)
{
    USE_INFO_2 ui = {
        0, 0, (PWSTR)password, 0, USE_IPC, 0, MAXDWORD, (PWSTR)username
    };

    ui.ui2_remote = (PWSTR)alloca((wcslen(lpMachineName) + 8) *sizeof(WCHAR));

    swprintf(ui.ui2_remote, L"\\\\%s\\IPC$", lpMachineName);

    ULONG ParmError, err;
    if (!(err = NetUseAdd(0, 2, (PBYTE)&ui, &ParmError)))
    {
        BOOL fOk = FALSE;

        if (SC_HANDLE hSCM = OpenSCManager(lpMachineName, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS))
        {
            if (SC_HANDLE hService = OpenService(hSCM, lpServiceName, SERVICE_START|SERVICE_STOP|SERVICE_INTERROGATE|SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS ))
            {
                SERVICE_STATUS ss;
                fOk = QueryServiceStatus(hService, &ss);
                //StartService(hService, 0, 0);
                //ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);
                CloseServiceHandle(hService);
            }
            CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
        }

        if (!fOk)
        {
            err = GetLastError();
        }

        NetUseDel(0, ui.ui2_remote, USE_LOTS_OF_FORCE);
    }

    return err;
}

// RemoteTest(L"192.168.122.100", L"Administrator", L"***", L"***");
```

and about your `void ImpersonateUser()` - at first it senseless (impersonate thread with current process token) at second not need open current process handle but can use constant pseudo-handle `GetCurrentProcess` or `NtCurrentProcess()` macro. and all this have no any effect. for `prepare to access remote system` - you need `NetUseAdd` call

Comment: Hi RBMn thanks it is working for me. is there any other way in which i don't need to give username , password . i.e. automatically detect user token because in my case i don't allow to plain text credential.

Comment: @DineshSaini - in user token not exist name/password and main it used only locally. remote system can not access your token for check. if your system assume send token to remote system - how remote can check that this info is true ? how I know or some kind of authentication need or way which advice  Harry Johnston - add LOCALCOMPUTERNAME$ into the remote computer's Administrators group

Comment: @RbMn  solution suggested by Harry Johnston is working but i don't know  how much it is safe. so if any other way to do start or stop service remotely please suggest

Comment: @DineshSaini - sorry, I don't know other ways, only this two

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a domain environment, you can change the service permissions on the target computer as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767296/886887)  The short version is that the permissions need to explicitly grant access to start and stop the service to the user account in question.

In this case, you will need to grant access to the domain account of the source computer.  Computer domain accounts take the form `COMPUTERNAME$`.